# how to access a variable outside onClick function react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get list from the onClick function but I can't if there any solution, please.
here is my full code [link](https://codeshare.io/1Y3qDX)

```
let abe = []
const click = (e) => {
    const cityy = e.target.value
    const checkUsername = obj => obj.city === cityy;
    const result = abe.some(checkUsername)

    if (!result) {
        abe.push({ "city": cityy})
    }

    if (!e.target.checked) {
        const indexe = abe.findIndex(p => p.city === cityy)
        abe.splice(indexe, 1)
    }

    const simo = watch("simo")
    let list = abe.map((list) => list.city).join(" , ")
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get a list"? Do you mean that you have a list state and you want to update it when a user clicks some button/input?

Comment: Please, add more description and code context.

Comment: let list = abe.map((list) => list.city).join(" , ")
I want to keep getting this string (list)

Comment: You want to access `let list` from outside the `click()` function ? Is that what you are trying to say ?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] or at least the code with more context. If `abe` is defined in the body of your function component then it is emptied at every render.

Comment: yes that's what i want @Dilshan

Comment: here is my full code [link](https://codeshare.io/1Y3qDX) _italic_ **bold**

Comment: You just need to declare `list` outside of the function as a `var` and you'll be good to go. `let` is block scoped meaning it can only be accessed in the block it is created within or below. It does not flow upwards/outside of the block. So attempting to access it elsewhere will result in it being undefined. If you're new to javascript I'd read this article explaining the scoping functions of vars, lets, and consts: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/

Comment: i tried it but doesnèt work because gives me only one value at time not string full of all values like "london, newyork,madrid"

Comment: but your way gives me one city at click

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is the click function triggered in the first place? You have actually missed to show where the click function is used.

Here is an example. Looks like you have to store cities in the state.

```
const [citiesList, setCitiesList] = useState<string[]>([]);


const click = (e) => {
    const cityy = e.target.value
    const checkUsername = obj => obj.city === cityy;
    const result = citiesList.some(checkUsername)

    if (!result) {
        setCitiesList(prevState => [...prevState, cityy]);
     
    }

    if (!e.target.checked) {
        const cList = [...citiesList];
        const indexe = cList.findIndex(p => p === cityy)
        cList.splice(indexe, 1);
        setCitiesList(cList);
    }

    const simo = watch("simo");
}
```

Comment: <SingleOption key={city.city}><Input onClick={click}  type='checkbox' value={city.city} />{city.city}</SingleOption>

Comment: Please move this to the comment section, as this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: here is my full code [link](https://codeshare.io/1Y3qDX) _italic_ **bold**

Comment: use useState and store your list there. 
const [listString, setListString] = useState('');

so then inside the click function set the string to the state. 
let list = abe.map((list) => list.city).join(" , ");
setListString(list);

then you can use listString outside the click function

Comment: i tried it but doesnèt work because gives me only one value at time not string full of all values like "london, newyork,madrid" 
and your way only gives me one city per click

Comment: I edited my answer. please check

Comment: <string[]>  gives me Parsing error: Unexpected token (68:56)eslint
An element access expression should take an argument.ts(1011)

Comment: if you are using javascript not typescript remove <string[]>. I just added that for your reference.